# Sequelize insert into join table (many-to-many)

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

I set up two models in sequelize that have a many-to-many relationship. Sequelize created the join table correctly, but I'm not able to insert into it. I've been poring over this section of the docs: http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/associations/#creating-with-associations but I can't get anything to work based on their examples. They don't have a many-to-many example, unfortunately.

Next I tried to use the setModel functions, and that's producing an error from deep in the sequelize code which I can't figure out. That code is below.

My two models are Coin and Ledger.

```
Ledger.findById(22).then(ledger=>{
    var c1 = Coin.findById(1);
    var c2 = Coin.findById(2);
    ledger.setCoins([c1,c2]).then(sc=>{
        console.log(sc);
    });
});
```

My models are related to each other using this code:

```
Ledger.belongsToMany(Coin,{ through: 'ledger_coin'});
Coin.belongsToMany(Ledger, {through: 'ledger_coin'});
```

Can anyone give me some suggestions or point me on the right track for either using the `get` functions or the association options to write to the join table? I could write a custom function but I know there must be a way to do it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, I solved the problem with `setCoins`, above. Apparently it takes id numbers and not objects, so this works:

```
Ledger.findById(22).then(ledger=>{
    ledger.setCoins([1,2]).then(sc=>{
        console.log(sc);
    });
});
```

I'd still like to understand includes and associations better, though.

Comment: Hi @fredrover, Did you find any better solution than setting the content

Answer (score 6):

### 2019+

After Sequelize 5+, `findById()` is replaced by `findByPk()`

```
Ledger.findByPk(22).then(ledger=>{
    ledger.setCoins([1,2]).then(sc=>{
        console.log(sc);
    });
});
```

Comment: How this can be done in typescript?
TS2339: Property 'setCoins' does not exist on type 'Ledger'.